# Running web3 from node.js powershell in none Administrator mode always shows an error

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nodejs

I am using Windows and installed web3js as general option "npm install web3@0.20.2 -g" using Windows powershell. I run powershell as administrator.

After installation i am able to get web3 object working **Web3 = require('web3')** only when i run cmd->node as administrator that is running by default from c:/windows/system32.

I want to be able to run code form VSCode terminal but i always getting an error:
Error: Cannot find module 'web3'

Can someone help with that? I guess it is an issue related to how installation of web3 was done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order by
up vote
0
down vote
I am not sure, but I thing the "-g" parameter must be before the package

npm install -g web3@0.20.2

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I thing the "-g" parameter must be before the package

```
npm install -g web3@0.20.2
```